# how to read from microphone in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am very new bee on this concepts of python, am just trying to explore on speechRecognation using python program.
I got a sample program as below:

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/microphone_recognition.py

and I tried another example from

https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/speech-recognition/

but it executes and hung at `audio = r.listen(source)`

I did try to trouble shoot the issue as mentioned at https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/ (trouble shooting section)
able to set deviceIndex still same issue.

**Setup details in windows**

> **pip install pyaudio**
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in c:\python\lib\site-packages
>   (0.2.11)
>
> **pip install SpeechRecognition**
>
> Requirement already satisfied: SpeechRecognition in
>   c:\python\lib\site-packages (3.8.1)

Can some one help me on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a different microphone? Have you tried setting a time limit on the length of time it records audio? .listen(timeout=<number>)